# Docker compose exporting ports is not working (according the docs)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am working in a local docker image that I created.

Now I am using docker-compose to send more parameters.

```
version: '2'
services:
  helloworld:
    image: helloworld:1.0
    environment:
      ports:
        - "8002:8002"
```

so, according the docker documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ports is the right way to do it

But everytime I try to run it I get that

```
services.helloworld.enviroment.ports contains ["8002"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null
```

I have tried removing the quotes, the - , different spaces and all have same results :s should be very simple but cannot figure it out, any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaml files are white space sensitive. With your indentation, you've placed the ports within an environment section where it doesn't belong. Instead you need it within your service:

```
version: '2'
services:
  helloworld:
    image: helloworld:1.0
    ports:
    - "8002:8002"
```

Comment: yeah, I had just changed and came to close it thanks for the answer, that is for sure the issue, it should be outside environment.